# jquery array items in single quotes

Tags: jquery, c#-4.0

We get the below array in jquery.

```
var grdXTcks = ["08/26", "09/09", "09/23", "09/26", "10/07", "10/10", "10/22", "11/05", "11/07"];
```

However I need the array to be like this to send it to jqplot:

```
var grdXTcks = ['08/26', '09/09', '09/23', '09/26', '10/07', '10/10', '10/22', '11/05', '11/07'];
```

can somebody advise is there a quick way to do this??

below is the data that I am sending to jqplot:

```
var grdYTcks =[20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 0, 70, 80, 90];
 var grdXTcks = ['08/26', '09/09', '09/23', '09/26', '10/07', '10/10', '10/22', '11/05', '11/07'];

        plot1 = $.jqplot(grphOneID, [grdYTcks, grdXTcks], {
            title: 'Highlighting, Dragging, Cursor and fsdfdsTrend Line',
            axes: {
                xaxis: {
                    renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                    ticks: grdXTcks,
                    tickOptions: {
                        formatString: '%#m/%#d'
                    },
                    pad: 0
                },
                yaxis: {
                    min: -10,
                    max: 110,
                    tickInterval: 10,
                    tickOptions: {
                        formatString: '%d'
                    }
                }
            },
            highlighter: {
                sizeAdjust: 10,
                tooltipLocation: 'n',
                tooltipAxes: 'y',
                tooltipFormatString: '<b><i><span style="color:red;">hello</span></i></b> %.2f',
                useAxesFormatters: false
            },
            cursor: {
                show: true
            }
        });
```

Thanks

Comment: Kindly show us how you passing data to jqplot.

Comment: if the grdXTcks are in double quote, trendline is not rendering. it should single quoted array..

Comment: Graph rendering at my End without error with the same code you provided.. What error you got when Use Double quote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are the same, both `"` and `'` are used to enclose string literals.

Comment: If it double quote, jqplot is not accepting. it is only accepting if it is surrounded by single